# Android Programming Google Map J2MEMapRouteAndroidEx Code -- negative latitude/longitude error

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I downloaded the package of J2MEMapRouteAndroidEx (link:http://code.google.com/p/j2memaprouteprovider/source/browse/trunk/J2MEMapRouteAndroidEx/src/org/ci/geo/route/RoadProvider.java).

But it reports error when I reset the latitude/longitude to negative value.The error is NullPointException... After an investigation into the Logcat, I think it indicated that the Road class object has not been really assigned value so that its array variables are null.

Could somebody please help? Anyone had the same problem before?